# Angular ngrx 8 selector doesn't return any value

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, redux, ngrx

I'm not new to Angular but I'm new to ngrx. 
I'm trying to get some values from my server and simply print them to the screen, I can see that the values are returning from the server after that the effect catches the action and do it's job:

[image]

but then my simple component doesn't show anything:

**ProfileComponent.ts:**

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  network$= this.store.select(a=>a.NetworkInfo)
  profiles$: Observable<Profile[]> = this.store.select(state => state.Profiles);
  constructor(private store:Store<NetAlertState>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch({ type: '[Profile Component] getAllProfiles' });
    this.store.dispatch({ type: '[Profile Component] getNetworkInfo' });    
  }

}
```

**profile.component.html:**

```
    <div *ngFor="let profile of profiles$ | async">
    {{ profile.name }}
    </div>
```

**net-alert.actions.ts:**

```
export const getAllProfiles = createAction('[Profile Component] getAllProfiles');
export const getNetworkInfo = createAction('[Profile Component] getNetworkInfo');
export const loadProfilesSuccess = createAction('[Profile Component] loadProfilesSuccess',props<{items:Profile[]}>());
export const loadNetworkInfoSuccess = createAction('[Profile Component] loadNetworkInfoSuccess', props<NetworkInfo>());
export const loadProfilesFailure = createAction('[Profile Component] loadProfilesFailure',props<String>());
export const loadNetworkInfoFailure = createAction('[Profile Component] loadNetworkInfoFailure',props<String>());
```

**net-alert.reducer.ts**

```
    export const initialState: NetAlertState = {
    Profiles:null,
    NetworkInfo:null,
    isLoading: false,
    error: null
}

export const NetAlertReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(NetAlertActions.getAllProfiles, state => ({ ...state,isLoading:true ,error:null})),
    on(NetAlertActions.loadProfilesSuccess, (state,profiles) => ({ Profiles:profiles,...state ,isLoading:false ,error:null})),
    on(NetAlertActions.loadProfilesFailure, (state,err) => ({ ...state,isLoading:false ,error:err})),
    on(NetAlertActions.getNetworkInfo, state => ({ ...state ,isLoading:true ,error:null})),
    on(NetAlertActions.loadNetworkInfoSuccess, (state,res) => ({ ...state,NetworkInfo:res,isLoading:false ,error:null})),
    on(NetAlertActions.loadNetworkInfoFailure, (state,err) => ({ ...state,isLoading:false ,error:err})),
  );



export function reducer(state: NetAlertState | undefined, action: Action) {
    return NetAlertReducer(state, action);
  }
```

**net-alert.effects.ts:**

```
@Injectable()
export class NetAlertEffects {

    loadProfiles$ = createEffect(() =>
     this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType('[Profile Component] getAllProfiles'),
        mergeMap(() => this.dataService.getAllProfiles()
          .pipe(
            map(res => ({ type: '[Profile Component] loadProfilesSuccess', payload: res })),
            catchError(() => of({ type: '[Profile Component] loadProfilesFailure' }))
          )
        )
      )
  );

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private dataService: DataService
  ) {}
}
```

**net-alert.state.ts:**

```
  export interface NetAlertState {
     isLoading: boolean;
     error: any;
     NetworkInfo: NetworkInfo;
     Profiles: Profile[];
 }

 export interface Profile {
  Mac: string;
  NickName: string;
  CreateDate: Date;
  Sites?: any;
}
```

**root-state.ts:**

```
export interface AppStates {
  netAlert: NetAlertState;
}

export const netAlertReducers: ActionReducerMap<AppStates> = {
    netAlert: netAlertRerucers.reducer
 };
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
  @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProfileContainerComponent,
    ProfileComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(netAlertReducers),
    EffectsModule.forRoot([NetAlertEffects]),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 25, // Retains last 25 states
      logOnly: environment.production, // Restrict extension to log-only mode
    }),
    RootStoreModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

is anyone can tell me where is my mistake?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is `Profiles: []` or similar showing in Redux DevTools when you choose "State" instead of "Action"? Toggle button is on top right in Redux DevTools. Also I don't see a selector for selecting the "netAlert" state, upon which you build the other selectors

Answer (score 1):

You should put your profiles$ in ngOnInit method like this

```
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  network$: any;
  profiles$: Observable<Profile[]>
  constructor(private store:Store<NetAlertState>) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch({ type: '[Profile Component] getAllProfiles' });
    this.store.dispatch({ type: '[Profile Component] getNetworkInfo' });
    this.network$ =  this.store.select(a=>a.NetworkInfo);
    this.profiles$ = this.store.pipe(select(state => state.Profiles));
  }
}
```

Also try to use pipe operator

Comment: @OrYaacov check my answer again

Answer (score 1):

It won't work if you don't have a reducer to update your state from `loadProfilesSuccess` action. Something like:

```js
const myReducer = createReducer(
  initialState, // type NetAlertState
  on(from.loadProfilesSuccess, (state, action) => {
     // return new state from action payload
  }),
)

export function reducer(state: NetAlertState, action: Action) {
    return myReducer(state, action);
}
```

You have actions but you never used them as well. You should use them everywhere:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(getAllProfiles());
    this.store.dispatch(getNetworkInfo());
}
```

```js
loadProfiles$ = createEffect(() =>
     this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(getAllProfiles),
        mergeMap(() => this.dataService.getAllProfiles()
          .pipe(
            map(res => loadProfilesSuccess(res)),
            catchError(() => of(loadProfilesFailure())
          )
        )
      )
    );
```

Comment: Actually I have reducers, I just didn't noticed that I didn't published theme here, 
I edited my document.

Comment: Your reducer code is wrong. The second parameter is `action`, so you need to use `action.payload` for your state. I am surprised that you do not have compilation error. Moreover, you must not have `Observable` in your `loadProfilesSuccess` action. And you should you this action in your effect instead of creating `{type: '...'}` manually.

Comment: first of all big thanks for the help. 
may I have small example or a bit more details? I can see where you are going but I still missing something

Comment: This is a code I wrote some months ago when I started learning ngrx: https://github.com/vannhi/angular-ngrx-leaflet-example/blob/master/src/app/app.effects.ts

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a selector for selecting the "netAlert" state, upon which you build the other selectors, like so:

*selectors.ts*

```
import * as fromNetAlertState from "./state";

export const netAlertState = (state: State) => state.netAlert;

export const selectProfiles = createSelector(
  netAlertState,
  (state: fromNetAlertState.State) => state.Profiles
);
```

*component.ts*

```
profiles$: Observable<Profile[]> 

ngOnInit() {
    this.profiles$ = this.store.pipe(select(selectProfiles))
}
```